# How can I search for a second pattern in vi without deleting the first search pattern

Tags: search, vi

In vi text editor, let's suppose I want to navigate through all instances of "cheese" in a text file, so I type "/cheese" and press ENTER. I can use n or N to go to the next/previous instances. If I change my mind and I want to search for "cheesecake", pressing "/" will delete "cheese" so I need to type "cheesecake" instead of only typing "cake".

Most graphical text editors will have the capability to save the last search pattern. Emacs also has this capability. I haven't found how to do this in vi.

Comment: I don't know about vi, but in Vim you can hit `/` and press up-arrow to scroll through previous patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of no way to make it keep the last command on the line when you open it but you are certainly able to press the up arrow and page through previous commands you've issued. So just type `/`, hit the up arrow key, type "cake".

PS - This doesn't really belong here. Stackoverflow is about programming questions. You might be better off asking this kind of question over at [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: That's pretty subjective. Vim isn't even an IDE.